# Submit action type to open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, review

I want to assign new action type to open graph.
I've added Read for example, and when I submit it says "Missing App Logo and Icon".
Well i have a logo on basic settings, but when I submitted the App details I got a message that it is pending review.

How long the review takes?
On the app details i've got this message:

App Center Listing Status: Unlisted
Your app is not listed because it does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be listed in the App Center at this time ....

Is this the review?

please help me, I just want to add open graph actions! that's my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to add open graph actions!

Forget of the app center for now, you can still use the open graph actions.

If the status its showing is pending, then wait till it is accepted.

> How long the review takes?

Its not fixed; generally more than 2 days. But could take a week too.

Comment: As I understand now the open graph depends on app details approval.
So for now i just have to wait for the approval of app details?

Comment: No, you are getting it wrong. The open graph approval doesnt depend on the app details. The app details is just for publishing the app in the APP Center of fb. You can ignore that for now. Just wait for the OG Action to get approved

Comment: this is what I get when i try to submit OG Action
[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fUsl3.png)
And i've uploaded all the required images for icons and stuff..

Comment: easy. just add the icon/logo in the app detail page. JUST these two.

Comment: This is app details page , which I understand is pending 
[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F5A8t.png)
- what should I do now?

Comment: "Primary Icons" in teh "App Detail" page. If you still have problem,  lets chat

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I have some progress now..
now i've got [this](http://i.imgur.com/583uj.png) step .
Do I have to pass this one to use the action?

Comment: Yes, give the exacts instructions so that the facebook can able to use your app and publish using OG. It will take at least 2 days to approve the actions. But as the admin, you may test without getting it approved also.